# NextJs Redirects if there is no cookie

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I want to redirect to /login page in /profile page if there is no token cookie. Here is my code:

```html
module.exports = {
  async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/profile',
        has: [
          {
            type: "cookie",
            key: "token",
            value: "undefined"
          }
        ],
        permanent: false,
        destination: '/login',
      },
    ]
  },
}
```